# Why is my toilet bubbling when other fixtures drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, septic

After having septic pumped out, main line professionally augered  and installed a new efficient toilet, water in toilet still bubbles when other drains empty. When laundry water drained, some came up in bathtub. All drains have also been treated with CLR, draining etc. Roof vent has also been checked, and treated for clogs. Septic pump has also been checked, and is working fine.

What could it possibly be now. December has been a very expensive month trying to rectify These problems.

Comment: You haven't said much about your plumbing system type and age. Please revise to add more information. This sounds like a vent problem, but any competent plumber should've already told you that.

Comment: First are the bubbles always there or only some times. You said there was a pump have the controls been checked there are usually 2-3 sensors in the pit and a septic tank really eats some of the connectors used. Since you had the line cleaned is it possible that some ? Is still in the line. I used to flush a small Styrofoam ball down the troubled line and run water if the ball did not come out it would be stuck at the problem location and I could feel it with the augger when it started cutting into the ball I used about a 3-1/4 inch ball for 4" pipe, they only cost about 50c.

Comment: Sounds like improper venting. If you have a large bolus of water pushing through the drain, without a nearby vent, it will push air back up into other drains, such as your tub or toilet. Without more info, it's hard to really say, though.

Comment: This is a one level old cottage sitting on blocks, with a drilled well. Occupied by 2 working people, with one bathroom. Last night after adding more drain cleaner to every drain, we tried to flush the toilet, and it clearly wasn't going to drain. Now it looks like we are plugged up again. Last week every thing was fine. No obvious reasons for this. Losing our minds. – Anne Erwin 1 hour ago   delete
     
Could anything be frozen. Last week's temperature dipped to -36. Just a thought. – Anne Erwin 1 hour ago   delete

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's best if you edit all this information into your question; you're more likely to receive a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Hari Ganti on this one. Sounds like a venting issue. Improper or partially clogged vent pipe.

Comment: This is a one level old cottage sitting on blocks, with a drilled well. Occupied by 2 working people, with one bathroom. Last night after adding more drain cleaner to every drain, we tried to flush the toilet, and it clearly wasn't going to drain. Now it looks like we are plugged up again. Last week every thing was fine. No obvious reasons for this. Losing our minds.

Comment: Could anything be frozen. Last week's temperature dipped to -36. Just a thought.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We prefer answers which are longer than a sentence or two, and include supporting information. It would help if you said why you thought venting was the problem, and how it could be cured.

Comment: Check the sewer vent pipe on the roof/in the attic: it may be clogged.